# Elements outside <BODY> is taken inside <BODY>

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, document-body, clonenode

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        </script>

        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=div1 style="border:5px solid green" onClick="alert(this.id)">hi
            <div id=div2 style="border:2px solid yellow">hello</div>
            <div id=div3 style="border:2px solid red">world</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <button onClick="document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('div1').cloneNode(true));">cloneNode</button>
</html>
```

I wanted to make the clone of the `div1` to appear above the `cloneNode`button and hence kept the button outside the `<body>`. But each time I click on the `cloneNode`button the new element appears below the `cloneNode`button although I appended the new node to the `<body>`element(using `appendChild()`) and the button is outside the `<body>` element. So, are all the elements even those outside the `<body>`(**as specified in the script**) included or considered inside the `<body>` at runtime. Please help me understand this.

Check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2K9U/)

Comment: You cannot have a button ouside the `<body>` element. Modern browsers will automatically move it to the end of the `<body>` element.

Comment: I think your should read up on HTML markup and proper use.

Comment: As you can check inspecting the DOM, the button is put inside the body. Can't be otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for this unnecessary mess. Could have used a container instead of `<body>`. Just tried to do it a easy way and found this principle, so was good for me. Thanx everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actual browser may rewrite invalid html (and, writing elements outside  is not really natural) . You can add an other surrounding div#id and use it to append correctly.

Try this (I also added quotes for element' ids):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        </script>

        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="main">
        <div id="div1" style="border:5px solid green" onClick="alert(this.id)">hi
            <div id="div2" style="border:2px solid yellow">hello</div>
            <div id="div3" style="border:2px solid red">world</div>
        </div>
         </div>
      <button onClick="document.getElementById('main').appendChild(document.getElementById('div1').cloneNode(true));">cloneNode</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually had this idea in mind after I got the unexpected result. So +1.

Answer (score 2):

Remove your clone button and  Add below code into above  tag,

```
<div id="AppendSection"></div>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('AppendSection').appendChild(document.getElementById('div1').cloneNode(true));">cloneNode</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2K9U/2/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish your goal is to move the button **inside** the `<body>` tag and put it at the end, but slightly modify the `onClick` action:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        </script>

        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=div1 style="border:5px solid green" onClick="alert(this.id)">hi
            <div id=div2 style="border:2px solid yellow">hello</div>
            <div id=div3 style="border:2px solid red">world</div>
        </div>
        <button onClick="this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.getElementById('div1').cloneNode(true), this);">cloneNode</button>
    </body>
</html>
```